# Hang problem in webControl and SAPI in C#

Tags: c#, sapi, freeze

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronization Problem for SAPI or (text to speech ) … C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221575/synchronization-problem-for-sapi-or-text-to-speech-c)

I've made a browser with WebControl. Now I want to read and highlight the text. So I split then sentences and start a loop.now the problem is, with a Synchronous call of SAPI to speak the sentences, every other button of the browser stops working. I can't pause, resume or even exit the software. Every button get hanged.

If I use a asynchronous call of SAPI, this problem doesn't occur, but then the highlighting of text will not work. So, I need to stick with this Synchronous call and also get over with this hang problem. Does anyone have any solution!!!!!!!

```
for (int i = 0; i < splitSentences.Length; i++)
{
    highlight(splitSentences[i]);

    sound_object.Speak(splitSentences[i]);
}
```

Please urgent help needed. How can I work out those pause, exit buttons of browser while speaking the sentece....

Comment: You cannot reasonably hang the user interface by making a synchronous call.  Use an event to detect progress.

Comment: Bro even if I off the highlight option totally still the buttons stop working with synchronous call.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Invoke in `HighLight` function.

For example,

```
void Do() //Must be start in another thread, not in main
{
    string [] splitSentences = new [] {"bye", "hello"};

    for (int i = 0; i < splitSentences.Length; i++)
    {
        HighLight(splitSentences[i], this);
        sound_object.Speak(splitSentences[i]);
    }
}

void HighLight(string str, Control webBrowser)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(s, c => HighLight(s, c)));
    }

    // Highlight code here
}
```

Comment: To reduce the response time you can use `BeginInvoke` rather then `Invoke`. Please note that calling BeginInvoke in WinForms doesn't require you to call EndInvoke later (but you still can do it if you wish). You can read a complete guide here: http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx.

Comment: @Dmitry Lobanov, I think the authour wants to highlight text in defined order, step by step... `BeginInvoke` may cause mixing of steps: step1->step3->step2.